# How to click the follow button on Instagram?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click the follow button on Instagram using Python Selenium
https://www.instagram.com/luvly_zuby/?hl=en

I've tried the bellow code but it's not working.

```
#click follow
    follow = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Follo")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(follow).click().perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the element by using simple selenium click by finding the element using its text in the xpath and then using explicit wait on the element.
You can do it like:

```
follow_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Follow']")))
follow_button.click()
```

You need to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
document

Comment: this solution worked for me i have been trying for hours to figure it out.. I still don't understand this process fully but thank you !! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Pass the WebElement to click(element) method.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('testUrl')
follow = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),'Follow')]')
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(follow).click(follow).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the element using this css selector `a.BY3EC > button` and wait using `.element_to_be_clickable`:

```
follow = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.BY3EC > button')))
follow.click()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```